# SSL server verfication by client in c

Tags: c, security, networking, ssl

I am building simple client server program and I am planning on using OpenSSL for securing message transfers.

I am planning on only having the client validate the server's certificate. I am confused on how I should verify the servers certificate from the client program. What are the constrains the client needed for the verification.if you have a sample code please provide it. Thank you.

Comment: It all depends on what it is you are specifically trying to verify. What does the client want to validate? What does the client know about the server that it wants to verify?

Comment: Client wants to verify the certificate of the server. what are the constrains that the client needs to do so?

Comment: What do they want to verify about the certificate, specifically? Do they know what certificate the server is supposed to have and want to know that it's that specific certificate? Is someone supposed to have signed the certificate and they know who that someone is? "Verify the certificate" doesn't make sense -- verify that the certificate ... what?

Comment: I have create a certificate for server which is self signed now the client has to verify and connect to server

Comment: Your task is to incorporate the following security features in this system:
1. Clients authenticate the echo server before sending/receiving messages
2. Communication between the client and the server is encrypted using a symmetric key
cryptographic algorithm
3. A new symmetric key is generated every time a client connects with the server
4. Both clients and server verify the integrity of the messages they receive
Use OpenSSL to incorporate these security features.

Comment: What does the client have to verify about it? Anyone can create a self-signed certificate, right?